# JSON input number замена значение при смене value

Tags: javascript, html, json

Подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью JSON массива данных, менять значение в блоке при увеличение value

Есть поле:

```html
<input type="number" value="1">

<div id="price"> . </div>
<div id="metr"> . </div>
```

А также есть массив данных:
{
"value" : "1",
"price" : "1000",
"metr" : "5"
},
{
"value" : "2",
"price" : "2000",
"metr" : "10"
},

Как сделать изменение значений в id=price и id=metr, при увеличение или уменьшение поля input

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
const massivDannyh = [
  { "value" : "1", "price" : "1000", "metr" : "5" }, 
  { "value" : "2", "price" : "2000", "metr" : "10" },
  { "value" : "3", "price" : "3000", "metr" : "15" }
];

window.onload = ()=>{

  const input = document.querySelector('#input');
  const price = document.querySelector('#price');
  const metr = document.querySelector('#metr');

  input.addEventListener('keyup',event=>{
    handlerChange(event.target.value);
  })
  input.addEventListener('change',event=>{
    handlerChange(event.target.value);
  })

  const handlerChange = (value)=>{
    const item = massivDannyh.find(i=>i.value===value)
    price.textContent = item?item.price:'.';
    metr.textContent = item?item.metr:'.';
  }
}
```